# How to protect link/url form ESP-12E for controlling LED

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu, http, home-automation

I am using ESP8266 ESP-12E NodeMCU for controlling LEDs and Relay.

When ESP-12e power on it connect into my home wifi network and it gives IP address such as 192.168.0.104, and by that I can control my devices through Localhost.

I am using link or url to control my application such as

192.168.0.104/status1=1 (for starting LED 1 start)

192.168.0.104/status1=0 (for turn off LED)

but my point is how to secure 192.168.0.104/status1=1 or 192.168.0.104/status1=0.

Because it is open for all and however if some one do just for fun and turn off my Relays and LEDs it will be very risky for home application.

Here is my code, this code works very well:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

const char* ssid = "Asif Wifi";
const char* password = "asif0172";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const int output1 = D1;
const int output2 = D2;
const int output3 = D3;
const int output4 = D4;

boolean device1 = false;
boolean device2 = false;
boolean device3 = false;
boolean device4 = false;

void handleRoot() {
  //digitalWrite(led, 1);
  //server.send(200, "text/plain", "hello from esp8266!");
  //digitalWrite(led, 0);

  String cmd;     
      cmd += "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n";
      cmd += "<html>\r\n";
      //cmd += "<header><title>ESP8266 Webserver</title><h1>\"ESP8266 Web Server Control\"</h1></header>";
      cmd += "<head>";
      cmd += "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3'/>";
      cmd += "</head>";

      if(device1){
        cmd +=("<br/>Device1  : ON");
      }
      else{
        cmd +=("<br/>Device1  : OFF");
      }

      if(device2){
        cmd +=("<br/>Device2  : ON");
      }
      else{
        cmd +=("<br/>Device2  : OFF");
      }

       if(device3){
        cmd +=("<br/>Device3  : ON");
      }
      else{
        cmd +=("<br/>Device3  : OFF");
      }

      if(device4){
        cmd +=("<br/>Device4  : ON");
      }
      else{
        cmd +=("<br/>Device4  : OFF");
      }

      cmd += "<html>\r\n";
      server.send(200, "text/html", cmd);
}

void handleNotFound(){
  //digitalWrite(led, 1);
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET)?"GET":"POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<server.args(); i++){
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
  //digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void setup(void){
  pinMode(output1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(output2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(output3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(output4, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(output1, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(output2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(output3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(output4, LOW);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");



  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");

  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());


  if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }

  server.on("/", handleRoot);

  server.on("/status1=1", [](){
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "device1 = ON");
    digitalWrite(output1, HIGH); 
    device1 = true;
  });

  server.on("/status1=0", [](){
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "device1 = OFF");
    digitalWrite(output1, LOW); 
    device1 = false;
  });

  server.on("/status2=1", [](){
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "device2 = ON");
    digitalWrite(output2, HIGH); 
    device2 = true;
  });

  server.on("/status2=0", [](){
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "device2 = OFF");
    digitalWrite(output2, LOW); 
    device2 = false;
  });

  server.on("/status3=1", [](){
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "device3 = ON");
    digitalWrite(output3, HIGH); 
    device3 = true;
  });

  server.on("/status3=0", [](){
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "device3 = OFF");
    digitalWrite(output3, LOW); 
    device3 = false;
  });

  server.on("/status4=1", [](){
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "device4 = ON");
    digitalWrite(output4, HIGH); 
    device4 = true;
  });

  server.on("/status4=0", [](){
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "device4 = OFF");
    digitalWrite(output4, LOW); 
    device4 = false;
  });

  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop(void){
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Only need to know how to secure this system, that's it.

Thank you.

Dear Garben,

well I am trying in your way but I can not add variable and can not operate by operator..... Here is my code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

const char* ssid = "Asif Wifi";
const char* password = "asif0172";

const char* pwd = "dada123456";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const int output4 = D4;

boolean device4 = false;


void handleRoot() {
  //digitalWrite(led, 1);
  //server.send(200, "text/plain", "hello from esp8266!");
  //digitalWrite(led, 0);

  String cmd;     
      cmd += "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n";
      cmd += "<html>\r\n";
      //cmd += "<header><title>ESP8266 Webserver</title><h1>\"ESP8266 Web Server Control\"</h1></header>";
      cmd += "<head>";
      cmd += "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3'/>";
      cmd += "</head>";


      if(device4){
        cmd +=("<br/>Device4  : ON");
      }
      else{
        cmd +=("<br/>Device4  : OFF");
      }

      cmd += "<html>\r\n";
      server.send(200, "text/html", cmd);
}

void handleNotFound(){
  //digitalWrite(led, 1);
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET)?"GET":"POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<server.args(); i++){
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
  //digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void setup(void){

  pinMode(output4, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(output4, LOW);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");



  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");

  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());


  if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
  }

  server.on("/", handleRoot);

  server.on("/status4=1&password=" + pwd, [](){
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "device4 = ON");
    digitalWrite(output4, HIGH); 
    device4 = true;
  });

  server.on("/status4=0&password=" + pwd, [](){
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "device4 = OFF");
    digitalWrite(output4, LOW); 
    device4 = false;
  });

  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop(void){
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: Use something like `192.168.0.104/status1=1&password=12345` for at least some very basic security.

Comment: Gerben: Ok sir I going to test it.

Comment: Dear Gerben please check question again I just update next problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at the [HttpBasicAuth](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/HttpBasicAuth/HttpBasicAuth.ino) example that comes with the ESP8266's ESP8266WebServer library that you are using. It is simple enough.

Here it is pasted in for reference:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "........";
const char* password = "........";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const char* www_username = "admin";
const char* www_password = "esp8266";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  if(WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi Connect Failed! Rebooting...");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }
  ArduinoOTA.begin();

  server.on("/", [](){
    if(!server.authenticate(www_username, www_password))
      return server.requestAuthentication();
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "Login OK");
  });
  server.begin();

  Serial.print("Open http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/ in your browser to see it working");
}

void loop() {
  ArduinoOTA.handle();
  server.handleClient();
}
```

The key part is this bit:

```
    if(!server.authenticate(www_username, www_password))
      return server.requestAuthentication();
```

Add that into your handler for your URL and it will ask for a username and password which you provide as `www_username` and `www_password`.

There's a more advanced example too if you want to delve deeper.

Comment: Ok..sir, Thank you. I will try it right now but I will tell you tomorrow.